# TypeError: number is not a function - Phonegap Sqlite

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying to make a connection in sqlite to retrieve some information...
I made this function in Jquery to phonegap.

```
getSQL: function(){
     var conect =  window.openDatabase("sqlLove", "1.0", "sqlLove", 1000000);
     conect.transaction(db.getQuery, db.errorDB, db.dbReady);
},

getQuery: function(tb){
    var sql = 'select celular from usuario limit 1';
    tb.executeSql(sql, [], db.getSuccess);
},

getSuccess: function(tb, results){
   var len = results.rows.length;
   //se for maior q 1 já existe dados para este celular
   if(len > 0){
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            var row = results.rows.length(i);
            console.log(results.rows.length(i));
            app.setUser(row.celular);
        }
   }else{  }
}
```

Is returning this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function  db.js:38
```

On line 38 I have it:

```
 var row = results.rows.length(i);
```

made an alert in the variable "len" and appeared returns 1, then is working, the problem being to show.

Thanks very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating line 38 to this:

```
var row = results.rows.item(i);
```

To get the actual data from the return you use `item` not `length`